# How to continue executing a stored procedure after error is logged in the CATCH block

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I've a requirement when a record fails to insert a record  into the table, error should be caught in the CATCH block and stored procedure should not stop because of that error.

Below is the scenario:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pkg_StoredProcedure]  
     @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(20), 
     @Parameter2 INT,
     @Parameter3 INT
AS  
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY 
BEGIN TRAN T1
    INSERT INTO Table1
        SELECT * FROM Table2

    COMMIT TRAN T1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRAN T1

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    INSERT INTO [ETL_ErrorLog]
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            column1, column2, column3, column4, 
            @ErrorMessage + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @ErrorSeverity ) + '/' + 
                 CONVERT (VARCHAR, @ErrorState)+ ')' as 'ErrorMessage'

END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: Place the RAISERROR  as the last statement

Comment: Did the above suggested but still fails. I tried by Uncommenting the RAISERROR   CATCHBLOCK  as shown in th eexample above still keeping the etl_Errorlog table . stored procedure executed successfully by logging the error in the ETL.Errorlog. Is this the best practice?

Comment: "error should be caught in the CATCH block and stored procedure should not stop because of that error." what other work need to perform after error.what is the other query in your store procedure ? what code should not stop after error ?

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario like this I would try to separate out the code, so that when the error occurs the entire process isn't interrupted

In other words the code:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT * FROM Table2

COMMIT TRAN T1
```

I'm assuming this is not the actual code?
Could you move this section, into another stored procedure, (with the try catch) and run a loop that calls this new procedure? Then when the error occurs the "called" procedure will fail but not the "calling" procedure.
Error will be logged, loop continues

Answer (score 0):

The `try / catch` construct is there to allow you control on exceptions instead of the default exit handler (meaning, abrupt procedure termination).

Whatever code is after the `END CATCH` would be executed if you are not exiting the procedure from within the `try / catch` blocks.

Note that in the example above you are triggering the error handling mechanism BEFORE the insert. As such, I suspect you are not seeing anything in your table `[ELT_ErrorLog]`.

Comment: when a record fails to insert  it is logging into the ETL_ErrorLog table in the CATCH block and fails.

Comment: It does not fail. The invocation of `RAISERROR` is what makes it exit the procedure. Comment it, add a `print 'Hi there'` immediately after the `END CATCH` and see if you get the printout (you definitely should!!).

Comment: Tried the  suggested  with  print out but  when  stored procedure is executed it shows both error message and print out message and logged a record into the Error Log as shown in the example.

Comment: this is what i want ...when the stored procedure is executed it should run successfully and log the error in the table. for that purpose when  RAISEERROR in the CATCH BLOCK  is removed in the above code noticed stored procedure executed successfully by logging the error in the error_log table.Can you please let me know Is this the best practice.

Comment: As stated, the purpose of `try-catch` blocks is to allow you to define **NON-DEFAULT** exception handling. In such case, you don't need the `RAISERROR` at all.